# Reset Alexa sessionAttributes

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-sdk-nodejs

At end of active session of user I wants to remove all sessionAttributes using `handlerInput.attributesManager`.

How to remove all sessions at end of AMAZOn.StopIntent

Answer (score 1):

Alexa ends it's active session when there is no input from the user even after reprompt, or the response itself has a `shouldEndSession` set to `true`, or there is an error in the response.  In all these cases the `sessionAttributes` are all cleared. So you don't have to explicitly clear it.

The user has open the skill again to interact with the skill and that will be a new user session with no `sessionAttributes` itself.

Now if you want to end the session which in turn clears the sessionAttributes you do:

In **ask-nodejs-sdk v2**,  don't specify a reprompt, this will set `shouldEndSession` set to `true` automatically.

```
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak("Bye")
      .getResponse();
```

In **ask-nodejs-sdk v1**,  use `:tell`, this will set `shouldEndSession` set to `true` automatically.

```
this.emit(':tell', 'Bye');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I found the solution,

```
handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes({})

return handlerInput.responseBuilder
.speak("Goody Bye")
.withSimpleCard('', "Goody Bye")
.withShouldEndSession(true)
.getResponse()
```